# How to disable JButton after two clicks?

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

I was wondering if it is possible that if a JButton is pressed twice then a button will disable itself, in other words it will .setEnabled(false);

This is the code i have so far. I want it so that if Respin is pushed twice then btnRespin will be set to false

```
      //This is the code for spinning the wheels once hold is pressed
  if (event.getSource() == btnHold1 && "THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE CODE FOR IF THE BUTTON IS PUSHED TWICE")
  {
      counter = 0;
      timer1.stop();
      btnHold1.setEnabled(false);
  }
```

Comment: Add a counter to your event source handler and if btnHold1 is pressed back to back then disable it.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a click counter

like an int i = 0; and increase it every click

and check when it is above 1

Comment: If you start at 0, then he'd need to check when it's above 1, rather than 2.

Comment: @TDorno do you mean like this
int clicked = 0;
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
 {                                         

  clicked++;
  System.out.println(clicked);
 }

Comment: @MichaelG Yes, but include some code after your clicked++ to check when it's above 1 and disable your button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are trying to achieve is possible.
If you want to count the no of clicks in that event you can use:

```
event.getClickCount() == 2
```

If you want to disable the button on a second click, ie: click once to enable then once more to disable. This is what appears to me you are trying to do.

```
event.getSource() == btnHold1 && (counter%2 == 0)
```

I would suggest to use the click event for that button and have an increment and check your counter. ex:

```
public counter = 0;
private void functionForButtonClick (Events, handlers etc..){
    counter++;
    if(counter%2 == 0){
        btnHold1.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: If i run the code
event.getSource() == btnHold1 && (counter%2 == 0)
then once btnHold1 is pressed then btnRespin is completely disabled.

i need it so that if Respin is pressed twice then it is disabled

Comment: Can you post the exact code snippet you are running ? counter%2 ==0 condition is satisfied only on increments of 2 units. As in every 2 clicks the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an actionListener and increment a counter for each event, you have a problem if the user clicks on the button, then 5 minutes later clicks on it again, it will see that second event as a double-click and disable the button. Presumably you want to disable it only if the user really double-clicks (within the system double-click interval), You can use your own timer to do this, or just use a MouseListener instead, with this code in it:

```
 @Override
 public void mousePressed( MouseEvent ev ) {
    if ( ev.getClickCount() == 2 ) {
       ((JButton)ev.getSource).setEnabled( false );
    }
 }
```

Note that the user can still use the space bar to push the button, but hitting space twice rapidly will not be seen as a double-click.

Comment: None of the solutions are working for me. I Need so that if btnRespin is pressed twice then it will disable itself. all solutions above are disabling btnRespin after "Hold1" is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  private class ClickHandler extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
     public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent ev ) {
        if ( ev.getClickCount() >= 2 ) {
           ((JButton)ev.getSource).setEnabled( false );
        }
     }
}
```

mouseClicked event would handle your key pressed and released event.